# Xamarin iOS SqLite.SQLiteException CannotOpen

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin (and C#) and I have been tasked with writing what is basically a network scanner. I am using Xamarin Forms as the application should work on both iOS and Android.

To begin with I just created an `ObservableCollection` to store the list of IP addresses that are generated by pinging devices on my network but I am now attempting to store these into a SQLite database.

I followed the [Xamarin tutorial on the subject](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) I have been able to get reasonably far. I have it so that it is saving into a database on Android and then displaying in a list view (although I am not particularly happy with how I am refreshing the contents of the list view but that is another question).

Unfortunately, on iOS I can't get the database to store the values. I get an `SQLite.SQLiteException (CannotOpen)` every time it tries to add the first IP address from the scan. I am using the [GBPing](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing) library (with Xamarin bindings) to perform the pings.

I added a call to my insert method before I start running the scan and it adds fine. I am at a loss as to why it will not run successfully in subsequent instances.

My data model class is:

```
using System;
using SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExampleUI
{
    [Table("Device")]
    public class Device : IComparable, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { 
            get {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ID SET");
                this._id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ID));
            }
        }

        private string _ip;
        public string ip
        {
            get
            {
                return _ip;
            }
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("IP SET");
                this._ip = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ip));
            }
        }

        private string _mac;
        public string mac
        {
            get
            {
                return _mac;
            }
            set{
                Debug.WriteLine("MAC SET");
                this._mac = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(mac));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Device()
        {

        }

        public Device(string ip, string mac)
        {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.mac = mac;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Device device = obj as Device;
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Device");
            }
            int lastOctet = 0;
            var octet = ip.Split('.').Last();
            Int32.TryParse(octet, out lastOctet);

            int lastDeviceOctet = 0;
            var deviceOctet = device.ip.Split('.').Last();
            if (Int32.TryParse(deviceOctet, out lastDeviceOctet) && Int32.TryParse(octet, out lastOctet))
            {
                return lastOctet.CompareTo(lastDeviceOctet);
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException("Last octet is not an integer");
            }
        }


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The database class is:

```
using System;
using SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ExampleUI
{
    public class DeviceDatabase: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        SQLiteConnection database;

        private ObservableCollection<Device> _devices;

        public ObservableCollection<Device> devices {
            get {
                this._devices.Sort();
                return this._devices;
            }
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SETTING OBSERVABLE COLLECTION");
                this._devices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("devices");
            }
            }

        public DeviceDatabase()
        {
            database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            Debug.WriteLine(database);
            database.CreateTable<Device>();
            this._devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>(database.Table<Device>());
            Debug.WriteLine("NO OF DEVICES IN COLLECTION:");
            Debug.WriteLine(_devices.Count);
            this._devices.CollectionChanged += _devices_CollectionChanged;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Device> GetDevices()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("RETURNING LIST OF DEVICES");
                List<Device> collection = database.Table<Device>().ToList();
                ObservableCollection<Device> devicecollection = new ObservableCollection<Device>(collection);
                devicecollection.Sort();
                return devicecollection;
            }
        }

        public Device GetDevice(int id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return database.Table<Device>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
            }
        }

        public int SaveDevice(Device item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SAVE DEVICE TO DB");
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (item.ID != 0)
                {
                    database.Update(item);
                    return item.ID;
                }
                else {
                    Debug.WriteLine(database.DatabasePath);
                    var query = database.Table<Device>().Where(v => v.ip.Equals(item.ip));
                    if (query.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        return database.Insert(item);
                    }
                    return 1;

                }
            }
        }

        public int DeleteDevice(int id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return database.Delete<Device>(id);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        void _devices_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("_devices_CollectionChanged");
        }
    }
}
```

The database is setup in the main `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

namespace ExampleUI
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static DeviceDatabase database;

        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DevicePage());
        }

        public static DeviceDatabase Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new DeviceDatabase();
                }
                return database;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

I make use of GBPing in a PingHelper class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Foundation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GBPinger;
using ExampleUI;



namespace GBPingHelper
{

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable
        {
            List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
                collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
        }
    }

    public class PingHelper : GBPingDelegate
    {
        ObservableCollection<ExampleUI.Device> _devices { get; set; }

        int currentPingers;

        public delegate void DeviceScanCompleteHandler(object sender, PingArgs e);
        public delegate void DeviceAddedHandler(object sender, PingArgs e);

        public static event DeviceScanCompleteHandler DeviceScanComplete;
        public static event DeviceAddedHandler DeviceAdded;

        [DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
        static internal extern int sysctl([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] mib, int mibsize, IntPtr output, IntPtr oldLen, IntPtr newp, uint newlen);

        public static Dictionary<String, String> AllMac = null;

        public PingHelper()
        {
            _devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
            currentPingers = 0;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HERE???? {0}", _devices.Count);
            return _devices;
        }

        public void pingSubnet(string subnet)
        {
            currentPingers = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
                string ip = subnet + "." + i.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("IP IS: {0}", ip);
                GBPing pinger = new GBPing();
                pinger.Host = ip;
                pinger.Delegate = this;
                pinger.Timeout = 1.0;
                pinger.PingPeriod = 1.0;

                pinger.SetupWithBlock((success, error) =>
                {
                    if (success)
                    {
                        pinger.StartPinging();
                        currentPingers += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
                        NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), delegate
                        {
                            pinger.Stop();
                            currentPingers -= 1;
                            pinger = null;
                            if (currentPingers == 0)
                            {
                                PingArgs args = new PingArgs();
                                args.Devices = Devices();
                                DeviceScanComplete(this, args);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to start");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //delegate methods
        public override void DidFailWithError(GBPing pinger, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidFailWithError {0}", error.ToString());
        }

        public override void DidSendPingWithSummary(GBPing pinger, GBPingSummary summary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidSendPingWithSummary {0}", summary.Host);
        }

        public override void DidFailToSendPingWithSummary(GBPing pinger, GBPingSummary summary, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidFailToSendPingWithSummary {0}", summary.Host);
        }

        public override void DidTimeoutWithSummary(GBPing pinger, GBPingSummary summary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidTimeoutWithSummary {0}", summary.Host);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveReplyWithSummary(GBPing pinger, GBPingSummary summary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidReceiveReplyWithSummary {0}", summary.Host);

            Dictionary<string, string> searchPattern = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            searchPattern.Add("ip", summary.Host);

            var device = Devices().FirstOrDefault(o => o.ip == summary.Host);
            Console.WriteLine("THE DEVICE IS: {0}", device);
            if (device == null)
            {

                Device deviceDetails = new Device(summary.Host, GetMACAddressByIp(summary.Host));
                //_devices.Add(deviceDetails);
                //_devices.Sort();
                Console.WriteLine("ADDED DEVICE: {0}", _devices.Count);
                //notify that a new device has been found
                PingArgs args = new PingArgs();
                args.Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
                args.Devices.Add(deviceDetails);
                DeviceAdded(this, args);
            }
        }

        public override void DidReceiveUnexpectedReplyWithSummary(GBPing pinger, GBPingSummary summary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidReceiveUnexpectedReplyWithSummary {0}", summary.Host);
        }

        //mac address methods

        public static String GetMACAddressByIp(String ip)
        {
            return GetMACAddressByIp(ip, false);
        }

        public static String GetMACAddressByIp(String ip, bool reset)
        {
            try
            {
                if (AllMac == null || reset)
                {
                    AllMac = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    int CTL_NET = 4;
                    int PF_ROUTE = 17;
                    int AF_INET = 2;
                    int NET_RT_FLAGS = 2;
                    int RTF_LLINFO = 0x400;
                    int[] mib = { CTL_NET, PF_ROUTE, 0, AF_INET, NET_RT_FLAGS, RTF_LLINFO };
                    var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
                    sysctl(mib, 6, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);
                    if (length == 0)
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                    var pBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
                    sysctl(mib, 6, pBuf, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    int off = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        short len = Marshal.ReadInt16(pBuf + off);
                        IntPtr paddr = pBuf + off + 36 + 56;
                        byte sinlen = Marshal.ReadByte(paddr);
                        uint addr = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(paddr + 4);
                        string ipAddress = new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(addr)).ToString();
                        paddr += sinlen;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        bool allZero = true;
                        for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++)
                        {
                            byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(paddr + 8 + m);
                            if (b != 0)
                            {
                                allZero = false;
                            }
                            if (sb.Length > 0)
                            {
                                sb.Append(":");
                            }
                            sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
                        }

                        String mac = sb.ToString();
                        if (!allZero)
                        {
                            AllMac[ipAddress] = mac;
                        }
                        off += len;
                        if (length <= off)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBuf);
                }
                if (AllMac.ContainsKey(ip))
                {
                    return AllMac[ip];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in GetMACAddressByIp:" + ex.ToString());
            }
            return "";
        }


    }
}
```

This is used in the iOS implementation of IPAddressManager interface (this is where the call to `App.Database.SaveDevice` is made (see method `DeviceAdded`):

```
using ExampleUI.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GBPingHelper;
using System.Linq;


[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IPAddressManager))]

namespace ExampleUI.iOS
{
    public class IPAddressManager : IIPAddressManager 
    {

        PingHelper helper;

        public event EventHandler<PingArgs> DeviceCollectionUpdated;
        public event EventHandler DeviceCollectionScanStarted;
        public event EventHandler DeviceCollectionScanComplete;

        public IPAddressManager()
        {
            helper = new PingHelper();
            PingHelper.DeviceScanComplete += DeviceScanCompleted;
            PingHelper.DeviceAdded += DeviceAdded;

        }

        public String GetIPAddress()
        {
            String ipAddress = "";

            foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
                    netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                {
                    foreach (var addrInfo in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (addrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            ipAddress = addrInfo.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return ipAddress;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ExampleUI.Device> Devices()
        {
            return helper.Devices();
        }

        public void PingSubnet()
        {
            DeviceCollectionScanStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            string ipaddress = GetIPAddress();
            string[] octets = ipaddress.Split('.');
            var subnetOctets = octets.Take(octets.Length - 1);
            String subnetString = String.Join(".", subnetOctets);
            helper.pingSubnet(subnetString);
        }


        public void DeviceScanCompleted(Object sender, PingArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HERE AT LAST {0}", args.Devices);
            DeviceCollectionScanComplete(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void DeviceAdded(Object sender, PingArgs args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ADDRESS ADDED {0}", args.Devices[0].ip);
            App.Database.SaveDevice(args.Devices[0]);
            DeviceCollectionUpdated(this, args);

        }




    }
}
```

The view model that is bound to the values of the `ListView` is (notice that I make a call to `App.Database.SaveDevice` in the constructor that works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ExampleUI
{
    public class MainPageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool isLoading;
        bool isRefreshing;
        bool devicePresent;

        private Command refreshDeviceCommand;

        public Command RefreshDeviceCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return refreshDeviceCommand ?? (refreshDeviceCommand = new Command(ExecuteRefreshDeviceCommand, () =>
                {
                    return !IsRefreshing;
                }));
            }
        }

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return isLoading;
            }
            set
            {
                isLoading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get
            {
                return isRefreshing;
            }
            set
            {
                isRefreshing = value;
                Debug.WriteLine("SETTING REFRESHING TO {0}", value);
                OnPropertyChanged("IsRefreshing");
            }
        }

        public bool DevicePresent
        {
            get
            {
                return devicePresent;
            }
            set
            {
                devicePresent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DevicePresent");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Device> _devices;

        public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices { get
            {
                return this._devices;
            }
            set
            {
                this._devices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Devices");
            }
        }

        //public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices
        //{
        //  get
        //  {
        //      //return DependencyService.Get<IIPAddressManager>().Devices();
        //      return App.Database.devices;
        //  }
        //}

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            IsRefreshing = false;
            DevicePresent = false;
            DependencyService.Get<IIPAddressManager>().DeviceCollectionUpdated += DeviceCollectionUpdated;
            DependencyService.Get<IIPAddressManager>().DeviceCollectionScanComplete += DeviceCollectionScanComplete;
            //Devices = App.Database.devices;
            Devices = App.Database.GetDevices();
            App.Database.SaveDevice(new Device("192.168.0.1", "00:00"));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteRefreshDeviceCommand()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteRefreshDeviceCommand");
            Debug.WriteLine(isRefreshing);
            if (IsRefreshing)
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("WILL REFRESH");
                DependencyService.Get<IIPAddressManager>().PingSubnet();
            }

        }

        void DeviceCollectionUpdated(object sender, PingArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DEVICE COLLECTION UPDATED");
            IsLoading = false;
            DevicePresent = true;

        }

        void DeviceCollectionScanComplete(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DEVICE COLLECTION SCAN COMPLETE");

            IsLoading = false;
            DevicePresent = true;
            IsRefreshing = false;
            Devices = App.Database.GetDevices();
        }


    }
```

the Exception caught window looks as follows:

[image]

iOS Implementation of ISQLite:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ExampleUI.iOS;
using SQLite;
using Foundation;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_iOS))]
namespace ExampleUI.iOS
{
    public class SQLite_iOS: ISQLite
    {
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "Device.db3";
            var docs = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0];
            string documentsPath = docs.Path;
            string libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance you can offer would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Adam.

Comment: Can you add the content of the class file in iOS project implementing the ISQLite?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - just back from holiday. I have added the ISQLite implementation.

Comment: Hope you had a great holiday :) Anyways, coming back to the point, can you check the value of the **path** variable. I see that you already have the Console.WriteLine(path) but it would be great if we can get to know about the value.

Comment: The value for the path is:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4E7AFD4-4A30-469A-BC6A-0D64D0F2B863/Documents/../Library/Device.db3

Comment: The path looks correct. It's really weird that the connection is failing. Do you think it's possible to upload your code to git and share a link? I would liike to debug and see what's causing this issue.